# How to refresh WPF AutomationElement with DataTemplate - Windows UI Automation

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-automation

I am trying to automate the testing of a WPF application using [Windows UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/uiauto-uiautomationoverview).

The application has a [ContentControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol?view=netframework-4.7.2) with a data template that changes based on user interaction.

On initial load, I am able to get and click a button inside of the content control. This switches the data template (the sub-controls are removed and replaced with other ones).

However, when I look for the new controls in the automation element, they cannot be found.

I am using the wrapper [FlaUI](https://github.com/Roemer/FlaUI), but I've also tried [White](https://github.com/teststack/white) and they both have the same sort of result.

I am not using caching, but it seems like the window is somehow cached. Is there a way to reload the element or entire window so that I can retrieve the new controls.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution on [FlaUI's FAQ](https://github.com/Roemer/FlaUI/wiki/Common-Issues).

> When using DevExpress controls, some things (like tab content) are not
>   updated By default, DevExpress controls do not raise automation
>   events, as these events may decrease the application performance. To
>   make sure that the events are raised properly, set the
>   ClearAutomationEventsHelper.IsEnabled static property to false on
>   application startup (needs to be done in the application that is
>   automated with FlaUI):
>
> ClearAutomationEventsHelper.IsEnabled = false;